# Permission denied when trying to read a .crt file - Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android, certificate

I am trying to read a self-generated certificate in Android Studio. I have generated a RSA certificate with these commands:

```
$ openssl genrsa -out rsaprivkey.pem 1024
$ openssl req -new -x509 -key rsaprivkey.pem -out rsacert.pem
```

When trying to read it in Android Studio I get "java.io.FileNotFoundException:

/storage/self/primary/Download/ca.crt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)"

The code used is.

```
 public void readCertificate() {
    try {

        CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("/storage/self/primary/Download/ca.crt");
        X509Certificate cer = (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(is);
        PublicKey key = cer.getPublicKey();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have added in the manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Does anyone know what the problem can be?

Comment: /storage/self/primary is a non existing path as far as i know. Check for yourself using File.exists().

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, thanks!

Comment: But... I now saw that it does exist on some emulators i tried.